# How to estimate Range, Doppler and Angle with FMCW MIMO Radar?

Tags: phase, radar, doppler, mimo, channel

I am trying to obtain the range, Doppler and angle of arrival estimation with an TDM MIMO FMCW radar.
Actually, I have completed this process. In doing so, however, a few things remained unclear. First of all, I ran the process as an FFT in fast time to estimate the range then another in slow time to estimate the Doppler information. Those FFTs were processed for all virtual channels seperately.

First unclear part; to detect the targets, a predetection matrix should be constructed. This is explained as all virtual chanels' range-doppler maps should be summed nonchorently. As I understand, I should not use the phase information of those range-doppler maps. Is the mentioned phase information the calibration information of the channels or the phase information resulting from the Doppler FFT and what I need to do?

Second unclear part; between the detection (CFAR) process and the angle FFT, a Doppler correction step must be performed in order to correct for any velocity induced phase change. I don't understand that part.
Could you please advise me on these? Or can you suggest an article or tutorial?

Kind Regards

Abdullah

Comment: I am sorry that I do not have an answer to your question, but I am currently involved in a project with MIMO Radars and I cannot seem to find a resource to understand its workings and how to construct the Radar data cube and the signal processing stages. Would you please recommend any good resources?

Comment: Hi, you can check this article for TDM-MIMO radar:
https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9658500

Comment: Can I ask some question about TDM MIMO. How did you use time division multiplexing? I think you have more than one transmit antenna. Are you transmitting them all at separate intervals? How exactly is this done?